# controller spec not logging in my factory created user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, factory-bot

I've got a problem with my controller tests for my Courses Controller. It seems that devise is not signing in my user correctly. All the generated controller tests for this controller only are failing.

I create my user in users.rb using Factory-girl as per below...

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do 
    sequence :email do |n| 
      "test#{n}@email.com"
    end
    password "password"
    password_confirmation "password"
  end
end
```

Then in my courses_controller_spec.rb I simulate the login as per below..

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe CoursesController do
  include Devise::TestHelpers

  before(:each) do
    #@request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
    user = Factory.create(:user)
    user.toggle!(:admin)
    sign_in user
  end

  describe "DELETE destroy" do
    it "redirects to the courses list" do
      course = Factory.create(:course)
      delete :destroy, {:id => course.to_param}, valid_session
      response.should redirect_to(courses_url)
    end
  end
```

And I get the output...

```
Failure/Error: response.should redirect_to(courses_url)
Expected response to be a redirect to <http://test.host/courses> but was a redirect to <http://test.host/users/sign_in>
```

Please note I've also used the following in my spec_helper.rb

```
config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
```

And I've tried it as per https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Controllers-and-Views-tests-with-Rails-3-%28and-rspec%29

In my request specs I can create the user and login using the below which works fine but I'd like to get all the controller tests working also

```
fill_in "Email", :with => user.email
fill_in "Password", :with => user.password
click_button "Sign in"
```

Any help here would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just figured this out myself.  Remove the valid_session from your delete call.  That seems to overwrite the session defined using the devise test helpers.

Everything else seems correct.  Keep all the devise setup code and just change the delete line in your spec to:

```
delete :destroy, {:id => course.to_param}
```

I also kept in the following line in my `before( :each )` block, which you commented out.  Not sure what it does yet:

```
@request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
```